# Fluent API left join in Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In a .NET Core Web Api using Entity Framework Core I have all my controllers written using the fluent API methods.

I have a table (Employee) with several nullable foreign keys and what I expected to get was a list of eight entries (eight entries are defined in the database) with attached subclasses or null (if foreign key is null, e.g. on department).

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "isActive": true,
    "project": {
      "name": "string",
      "priorityLevel": 0,
      "riskLevel": 0,
      "clientCount": "string"
    },
    "employmentStatus": {
      "name": "string"
    },
    "salaryBoundary": {
      "salaryLimit": 0
    },
    "department": {
      "name": "string",
      "employeeCount": 0,
      "averageIncome": 0,
      "isSuccessfull": true
    }
  }
]
```

What I get is an empty list since Entity Framework Core decides to use inner joins.

So far I spent two days to convice EFC to use left outer joins with every tutorial I found on the internet.

I followed the Read the docs examples but in my case (according to the github post) using include is wrong.

I can't use (the often suggested DefaultIfEmpty() method since this is not availabe and does not compile.

I tried my luck in the official Entity Framework Core Github site wihtout success (it seems this is the intended behavior but this doesn't fix my problem).

When I search here on StackOverflow I find examples but they do not use the fluent API and I can't figure out how to translate them.

My current controller looks as following:

```
[HttpGet(Name = "ListEmployees")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ICollection), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary), 400)]
[SwaggerOperation("ListEmployees")]

public IActionResult ListEmployees([FromQuery] bool hideInactive = false)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("{0}.ListEmployees(hideInactive: {1})", GetType().Name, hideInactive);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("{0}.ListEmployees(hideInactive: {1}) > bad request due to invalid ModelState: {2}", GetType().Name, hideInactive, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ModelState));
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var query = _dbContext.Employee
        .Include(ee => ee.Department)
        .Include(ee => ee.SalaryBoundary)
        .Include(ee => ee.Project)
        .Include(ee => ee.EmploymentStatus)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .AsQueryable();

    if (hideInactive)
    {
        query = query.Where(ee => ee.IsActive == true);
    }

    query = query.OrderBy(ee => ee.Id);


    Pagination pagintation = Pagination.FromRequest(Request);

    if (pagintation.IsEnabled)
    {
        pagintation.TotalElements = query.Count();

        query = query.Skip(pagintation.SkipItems).Take(pagintation.ItemsPerPage);

        Pagination.ToResponse(Response, pagintation);
    }

    List result = query
                                .Select(ee => new EmployeeView()
                                    {
                                        Id = ee.Id,
                                        Name = ee.Name,
                                        IsActive = ee.IsActive,

                                        Project = (ee.Project == null) ? null :
                                            new ProjectView()
                                            {
                                                Name = ee.Project.Name,
                                                ClientCount = ee.Project.ClientCount,
                                                PriorityLevel = ee.Project.PriorityLevel,
                                                RiskLevel = ee.Project.RiskLevel
                                            },

                                        EmploymentStatus = (ee.EmploymentStatus == null) ? null :
                                            new EmploymentStatusView()
                                            {
                                                Name = ee.EmploymentStatus.Name
                                            },

                                        SalaryBoundary = (ee.SalaryBoundary == null) ? null :
                                            new SalaryBoundaryView()
                                            {
                                                SalaryLimit = ee.SalaryBoundary.SalaryLimit
                                            },

                                        Department = (ee.Department == null) ? null :
                                            new DepartmentView()
                                            {
                                                Name = ee.Department.Name,
                                                EmployeeCount = ee.Department.EmployeeCount,
                                                IsSuccessfull = ee.Department.IsSuccessfull,
                                                AverageIncome = ee.Department.AverageIncome
                                            }
                                    }
                                )
                                .ToList();


    return Ok(result);

}

[HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = "GetEmployeeById")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(EmployeeView), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ICollection), 404)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary), 400)]
[SwaggerOperation("GetEmployeeById")]
public IActionResult GetEmployeeById(int id)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("{0}.GetEmployeeById(id: {1})", GetType().Name, id);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("{0}.GetEmployeeById(id: {1}) > bad request due to invalid ModelState: {2}", GetType().Name, id, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ModelState));
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    EmployeeView result = _dbContext.Employee
        .Include(mp => mp.Department)
        .Include(mp => mp.SalaryBoundary)
        .Include(mp => mp.Project)
        .Include(mp => mp.EmploymentStatus)
        .Where(mpf => mpf.Id == id)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Select(ee => new EmployeeView()
            {
                Id = ee.Id,
                Name = ee.Name,
                IsActive = ee.IsActive,

                Project = (ee.Project == null) ? null :
                                            new ProjectView()
                                            {
                                                Name = ee.Project.Name,
                                                ClientCount = ee.Project.ClientCount,
                                                PriorityLevel = ee.Project.PriorityLevel,
                                                RiskLevel = ee.Project.RiskLevel
                                            },

                EmploymentStatus = (ee.EmploymentStatus == null) ? null :
                                            new EmploymentStatusView()
                                            {
                                                Name = ee.EmploymentStatus.Name
                                            },

                SalaryBoundary = (ee.SalaryBoundary == null) ? null :
                                            new SalaryBoundaryView()
                                            {
                                                SalaryLimit = ee.SalaryBoundary.SalaryLimit
                                            },

                Department = (ee.Department == null) ? null :
                                            new DepartmentView()
                                            {
                                                Name = ee.Department.Name,
                                                EmployeeCount = ee.Department.EmployeeCount,
                                                IsSuccessfull = ee.Department.IsSuccessfull,
                                                AverageIncome = ee.Department.AverageIncome
                                            }
            }
        )
        .SingleOrDefault();

    if (result == null)
    {
        return NotFound(new NotFoundInfo("id", id).AsCollection());
    }

    return Ok(result);

}
```

---

Overthere at the [Github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/9051) on the top of my first post is an .zip file attached which contains a Visual Studio 2015 project allowing to test the problem using swagger ui and see the generated SQL statements in the log files. There is even a Create-DB.sql script added which creates the datastructure in question.

---

So my question: how is the code (using fluent api) that produces left outer joins and returns the full list (with 8 entries) and objects attached (if foreign key is not null or null if foreign key is null)?

I am using Entity Framework Core 1.1.0, Visual Studio 2015 and IIS Express with a local SQL database.

---

### Update 1:

On Github I received a workaround creating the left joins. The problem seems not to be the query itself (although the includes are not necessary and seem to throw exceptions in newer versions).

The solution can be found in the generated DatabaseContext class (by scaffolding the DB). For the nullable foreign keys a

```
.IsRequired()
```

call is generated which is wrong and causes the left joins.

```
modelBuilder.Entity(entity =>
{
  // other entities

    entity.Property(e => e.DepartmentId)
        //.IsRequired()
        .HasColumnName("DepartmentID");
```

And of course remove the

```
.Include()
```

calls from the query.

Comment: EF core defines the query based on your model. If the foreign key is required in your model an inner join is used. What datatype is the foreign keys in your model, int vs int? (nullable)?

Comment: in the DB it was used as nullable tinyint and in code it is a nullable byte. Seems to be a fixed bug in the scaffolding.

Comment: Well seems you figure it out. .Include produces inner joins depending on how you configure your models. If the fks are nullable, change your model so they are not required anymore.

Comment: Actually that happend on only one table (out of 40) with nullable foreign keys. All the others didn't have the IsRequired in the generated code.